# Send message from ubuntu CLI to ubuntu Desktop via iptux

Tags: command-line, server, bash

I want to send a text message on iptux from the command prompt. I have tried with netcat but I believe that iptux has its own message frame.

I want to achieve the following anyhow:

1. On the local server machine script is running to watch all apache errors.
2. That bash script will call a command and send those error messages to the user (developer) via iptux.

Please suggest any solution.